# AbstractSet different logic

Tags: java, abstractset

In [AbstractSet.removeAll()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractSet.java) there are two codes to mark set as modified.

AbstractSet is

```
   public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        boolean modified = false;

        if (size() > c.size()) {
            for (Iterator<?> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
                modified |= remove(i.next()); //1
        } else {
            for (Iterator<?> i = iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                if (c.contains(i.next())) {
                    i.remove();           //2
                    modified = true;      //2
                }
            }
        }
        return modified;
    }
```

What could be the logic behind that the second (//2) is not `modified |= remove(i.next());` as the first (//1)?

I would rewrite the second (//2) to be the same as first (//1) to not have extra check (`contains(i.next())`).

```
   public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        boolean modified = false;

        if (size() > c.size()) {
            for (Iterator<?> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
                modified |= remove(i.next()); //1
        } else {
            for (Iterator<?> i = iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                i.next();
                modified |= i.remove()); //2
            }
        }
        return modified;
    }
```

**Update1**: `i.remove()` returns void. 
**Update2**: i.remove() would empty the set which is not welcomed result.
Based on update1, update2 this rewrite would not work.

Comment: it's `|=`, not `!=`! Important difference!

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @StephenC thank you. Corrected the link :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first call uses Set.remove(), the second one Iterator.remove().

The point is: the first one does return a boolean value, so the "final" result can be computed by "or'ing" the results of calls to set.remove().

Whereas the second iterator.remove() doesn't return anything - it is a void method! Thus you need a different way to "compute" that boolean value there!

Comment: You are correct it is void method.:) I assumed it's boolean. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, it took me a few seconds to understand that as well. It always helps to look at javadoc ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The only way to safely remove elements from a `Collection` (the `Set` for which `removeAll` was called) while iterating over it is with the `Iterator`s `remove` method. Using `remove(i.next())` will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

On the other hand, the first loop doesn't iterate over the `Set` from which the elements are to be removed (it iterates over the `Collection` passed as an argument). Therefore `remove(i.next())` can be safely called.

Another distinction between the two loops is that in the first, `remove(i.next())` is not guaranteed to remove anything from the `Set` (since the element to be removed may not be in the `Set`), so you want to OR all the results of the `remove` calls to determine if anything was removed. That's the reason for `modified |= remove(i.next());`.

On the other hand, when using `Iterator`'s remove, you know for sure an element was removed (that's probably the reason why `Iterator`'s remove doesn't return anything - if it did, it would always return `true`) so you can simply set `modified` to `true` after removing the first element.

EDIT:

Regarding your edit, which suggests rewriting the second loop to remove the `contains(i.next())` check - even disregarding the compilation error in `modified |= i.remove())` (resulting from the void return type of `Iterator`'s remove), that would empty the `Set` instead of removing just the elements of `c` that are present in the `Set`.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation :).

Comment: @Willmore Note that the important issue is that `modified |= remove(i.next());` can't be used in the second loop (not that `Iterator`'s remove has a `void` return type).